# ForEach ADO Enumerator

Tags: ssis

I have an Execute SQL Task which runs a simple query

datatype filename varchar(255) filenumber int id uniqueidentifier

select i.filename , i.filenumber,s.id , 'Files loaded over days' as ErrorMessage from table I inner join tableB s on i.filenumber = s.filenumber where datediff(day,i.filedate,i.adddate)>=5

I have added the resultset as user:ObjServiceID

Now I have used a Foreach ADO Enumerator and in Ado Object Source variable called user::objServiceID

Variable mappings User:ID 0 User::Filenumber 1 User::Filename 2 User::Errormessage 3

and inside the ForEach Loop container I have another Execute Sql task that calls a Stored procedure Parameter Mappings User:: ID GUID 0 -1 User::Filename Varchar 1 -1 User :: Filenumber Numeric 2 -1 User::ErrorMessage Varchar 3 -1

The stored procedure Exec XYZ has variables @filename varchar (255), @filenumber int, @id uniqueidentifier, @Errormessage varchar(2000)

I am constantly getting an error that says "[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "exec XYZ" failed with the following error: "Procedure or function "XYZ" expects parameter '@ErrorMessage', which was not supplied.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly."

Even if I try to remove the Errormessage from the parameter and variable mappings it still throws this error. Could someone help with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The m in Error message needs to be upper case in your mapping. It says ErrorMessage was not supplied because you have it as Errormessage.